# Slight width difference for the notification message text cell in Stack Exchange site achievements dialog

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, achievements-dialog

There is a slight width difference for the notification message text cell, in between the stackexchange.com and other Stack Exchange site's achievements dialog.

As per the screenshot below, same content is taking one more extra line to display other than stackexchange.com achievements dialog.

Can be the width of the message text cell is same as the stackexchange.com to all other Stack Exchange sites.

Screenshot from Meta Stack Exchange:

> [image: Meta Stack Exchange]

Screenshot from Stack Exchange:

> [image: Stack Exchange]

Comment: There have been some changes to the design of the Achievements dropdown since this was posted. However, the differences between the look of this dropdown on SE sites vs. stackexchange.com are relatively minor, and we're not prioritizing fixing this right now, so I've retagged this as [status-declined].